# Does HTTP/3 necessitate additional - beyond HTTP/2 via TLS1.3 - restrictions on client authentication (mTLS)?

Tags: tls, mutual, http2, quic

A recent Nginx release allows me to set `listen 443 quic;` to enable HTTP/3. Neat. I had been using HTTP/2 with TLS1.3 before, so I did not expect that change much, just optimize round trips with [otherwise matching security properties](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/75911/is-https-over-udp-secure).

One major change, though: Firefox will not send client certificates. Though it perfectly *could*:

- Same RSA+sha256 certificate fed to `aioquic` HTTP/3 example authenticates to same website.
- Same RSA+sha256 certificate is [offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847638/how-chrome-browser-know-which-client-certificate-to-prompt-for-a-site) by identical Firefox binary & profile via HTTP 1 or 2

Unfortunately, Firefox does not [tell me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477278/enable-tls-tracing-logging-in-firefox-snap-115) for what reason it choses to disregard the certificate request only while using HTTP/3.  **Am I missing some difference between TLS1.3 via TCP and QUIC?**

- Unordered packets complicate things a bit.. Maybe some security guarantee could not be upheld if this worked in QUIC exactly as it does over TCP?
- Renegotiating while multiplexing is not an option, right? I heard it was [outright banned in HTTP/2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8740) which [HTTP/3 keeps up](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9001#section-4.4).
- Maybe some limitations on which algorithms the certificate has to use? Yet the transport should not change the *authentication* part of the whole TLS dance, as that had already been [properly separated](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-1.2) from *record protection* when upgrading from TLS 1.2.

Comment: Noteworthy, but not an answer: QUIC differs in that to mitigate *packet reflection attacks* the server may only return to unverified sources only [3 times as much](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9000#section-8.1) as received. But not only does this not happen with small server certificates, it should also at most *delay* things until eventual recovery via probes; not changing the state transitions of the handshake.

Answer (score 0):

**I found none.** But someone might still identify such, during work that appears to have not started yet:

It just so happens that Mozilla had implemented [their QUIC library](https://github.com/mozilla/neqo) in Rust - using interfaces not entirely matching those of existing code in analogous role. This will hopefully reduce the cost of writing and maintaining secure & correct code. But it also means that every feature not (yet) receiving explicit patches to adapt to the new interface *and* design review to re-evaluate its impact with the new language and protocol, is dropped at that boundary.